# How to compute the cohomology with $G$ coefficients?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Show that $\tilde {H}^k ( S^n ; G)$ is $G$ if $k = n$ and $0$ otherwise.

So I need to calculate the cohomology groups of this  $\tilde {H}^k ( S^n ; G)$, could anyone help me in doing so please?

Comment: What tools are you allowed to use? Do you have the suspension isomorphism?

Comment: yes I have the suspension isomorphism @William

Comment: Do you have the universal coefficient theorem? This is another tool you could use.

Comment: I suggest you edit the title since $S^n$ is hardly ever a group and you are not computing group cohomology: You are asked to compute cohomology with $G$-coefficients.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I did it, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all $k\geq 0$ and all coefficients $G$ there is a suspension isomorphism

$$\sigma\colon \tilde{H}^k(X; G) \cong \tilde{H}^{k+1}(\Sigma X; G)$$

(In fact we get a suspension isomorphism for any generalized cohomology theory.)

Since $S^0$ has two components, $\tilde{H}^0(S^0; G) \cong G$. Then we can apply the suspension isomorphism $n$ times to get
$$ G\cong \tilde{H}^0(S^0;G) \cong\tilde{H}^n(S^n;G) $$